# Application responds very slow

Tags: hibernate, struts2, jstl

I built a web application using Struts 2, Hibernate. Has jQuery, html for the view part. I used the include directive to add header and footer templates. I am not sure which part is making to respond very slowly. Is this a kind of memory leak or  adding the headers and footers and translating them takes time. I think the later one has less probability because translating occurs only once right?.Does implementing a second level cashing solve the issue? How could I know it is a memory leak? or something else. Any suggestion could help me to improve the response time of my app. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind, that there are two kind of jsp include — static with `@include` and dynamic with `jsp:include`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I used @include which i thought is best for performance.

Comment: Yes, it is the best.  Try to log times of database queries.

Comment: I did the log and it looks like this 
starting 0.000067
checking permissions
0.000015
Opening tables
0.010598
init
0.007778
System lock
0.000039
optimizing
0.000011
statistics
0.000024
preparing
0.000023
executing
0.000006
Sending data
0.000118
end
0.000009
query end
0.000012
closing tables
0.000021
freeing items
0.000115
cleaning up
0.000034

Comment: Do you think I need to have indexing and how far will this improve the performance?

Comment: Well, what is `opening tables` ? Seems the culprit, but in the end it only takes 0.01 seconds... what do you expect ? :P Also note that with Struts2 you can use <s:include /> in place of the <jsp:include />, and that both of them are completely different from @include, it's not a matter of performance but of different goals

Comment: @TesfaZelalem I think, a database performance is good.

Comment: ok, where else could be the bottle neck? I can even see the same kind of slow down while navigating from page to page which does not need database operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found unexpected reason why navigating from one page to the next took too long. This is not related to a database hit or memory leak, it is the template that I included in each page. I made one huge header template where all the jQuery, JavaScript, css files load to. While removing it from jsp files the application responded with normally.Now I have to work on that but this could become a problem for someone and I would like to share it. When you are inexperienced, you never know where your little mistake is, keep looking every where you can.